# Iterate through every row and compare to table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a large data table in PostgreSQL containing, among other information, a column for start date and end date. For each row, I am hoping to tally the number of other rows in the same table which contain an overlapping date range and create a new table with these values.

To calculate overlapping date range, I had been planning to use:

```sql
where (start_date between [target_start_date] and [target_end_date]) or 
      (end_date between [target_start_date] and [target_end_date]))
```

But I have no idea how to do this for each row while comparing to its own table and tallying a count of times this condition is met.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use a subquery and the `OVERLAPS` operator.

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE (t2.target_start_date,
                      t2.target_end_date) OVERLAPS (t1.target_start_date,
                                                    t1.target_end_date))
       FROM elbat t1;
```